# Different underlying parameter estimates for GAM fits

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm puzzling over why I get dramatically different results fitting multilevel GAM models in two distinct, but closely related, ways. As a bit of background, I have a sample of 300 `subjects` observed over 31 years (`time`). Each subject received one of four treatments (`trt`) at the start of the observation period. My goal is to estimate how individuals who received different treatments progressed along some `outcome` over time.

To start, I fit the following model using `gamm4`:

```
mod_1 = gamm4(
    outcome ~ 
        trt + 
        s(time, by = trt, k = 31), 
    random = ~ (time | subject), 
    data = df_test
)
```

where each treatment level was allowed to have it's own smooth time term. The resultant model appears to work as expected. Here's a summary of the smooth terms from this fit:

```
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                edf Ref.df      F p-value    
s(time):trtA  4.941  4.941  513.1  <2e-16 ***
s(time):trtB  7.175  7.175 1043.2  <2e-16 ***
s(time):trtC 12.311 12.311 2200.6  <2e-16 ***
s(time):trtD  9.331  9.331 1754.8  <2e-16 ***
```

And here's a plot of the estimate smooths:

[image: m1 smooths]

This model seems well-behaved, at face value, given that estimated smooths appear to approximate plots of the observed data.

Now, for a few reasons, I'd like to estimate a similar model using `mgcv::bam()` or `mgcv::gam()`. With that in mind, I gave the following model a run:

```
mod_2 = bam(
    outcome ~
        trt + 
        s(time, by = trt, k = 31) +
        s(subject, bs = 're') +
        s(subject, time, bs = 're'),
    data = df_test,
    discrete = TRUE,
    nthreads = 8
)
```

In my understanding, the difference between these two models is that `mod_1` estimates correlated random terms, while `mod_2` doesn't. **If that's the case, I'm wondering if it "makes sense" that the 2 produce *very* different model results.** Here's the output for `mod_2`:

```
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                      edf Ref.df       F p-value    
s(time):trtA     27.17752     18  244.55  <2e-16 ***
s(time):trtB     29.16971     20  636.33  <2e-16 ***
s(time):trtC     29.73943     23 1967.36  <2e-16 ***
s(time):trtD     29.58018     22 1252.04  <2e-16 ***
s(subject)      290.65157    296   54.38  <2e-16 ***
s(time,subject)   0.00208    296    0.00   0.668
```

And here's the corresponding plot of the estimated smooths:

[image: m2 smooths]

The EDF maxes out on `mod_2` and the resultant smooths are, as expected, rather complex. Again, simple exploratory plots of the observed data don't seem to support this level of complexity.

**So, with all of that being said, my question is: why might these models produce vastly different results?** I understand that they're slightly different models, in that `mod_1` is estimating a correlation b/t random effects, but I'm not sure of if that explains the difference. If it helps, I took a look at the variance components and--outside of the smooths---the estimates don't look too far off from one another. E.g.,

```
> VarCorr(mod_1$mer)
 Groups   Name         Std.Dev.  Corr 
 subject  (Intercept)  0.4274406      
          time         0.0001009 0.160
 Xr.2     s(time):trtD 5.8983832      
 Xr.1     s(time):trtC 8.1501253      
 Xr.0     s(time):trtB 4.8016773      
 Xr       s(time):trtA 3.7708726      
 Residual              0.4909512 

> gammit::extract_vc(mod_2)
      group    effect variance    sd sd_2.5    sd_97.5 var_prop
1 time:trtA Intercept    1.000 1.000  0.730 1.3690e+00    0.166
2 time:trtB Intercept    1.463 1.210  0.921 1.5880e+00    0.244
3 time:trtC Intercept    1.572 1.254  0.965 1.6290e+00    0.262
4 time:trtD Intercept    1.563 1.250  0.959 1.6290e+00    0.260
5   subject Intercept    0.261 0.511  0.471 5.5500e-01    0.043
6   subject      time    0.000 0.000  0.000 3.0016e+61    0.000
7  Residual              0.149 0.386  0.380 3.9200e-01    0.025
```

The `subject` intercepts differ a little (the population-level intercept is about 9.5) and the `subject` specific time slopes are both about 0. The estimated correlation in `mod_1`, missing from `mod_2` is only about 0.16.

Any help thinking through this is appreciated!